# Как добавить свою библиотеку в autoload.php?

Tags: php

Есть папка с проектом. Внутри нее установлены пакеты в /vendor/ с помощью composer. Внутри /vendor/ есть сгенерированный при установке автозагрузчик autoload.php, который я подключаю на своих страницах.

Вопрос - в какую папку мне лучше складывать свои классы и как организовать их автозагрузку?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно свой код кладут в папку `src`, расположенную в корне проекта на одном уровне вложенности с `vendor`.
Чтобы подключить автозагрузку в ней необходимо добавить в `composer.json`

```
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src"
        }
    }
```

После этого следует выполнить команду `composer dump-autoload`.